# Pulling data from a webserver

Tags: python, database, webserver

I have made scrapers to pull data from websites(such as movies), but how do I connect to a websites server to pull the data straight from there database instead of making a crawler to pull data from the visual site? If you can give me the library name, set of tools or a guide that you be cool.

extra:
Does the request library do this the get a post functions?

Comment: Most major sites have APIs, or alternative solutions exists. Ex: http://www.omdbapi.com/ for movies.

Comment: You generally can't make arbitrary database queries - that would be a massive security flaw.  Major sites tend to have APIs, and in some cases it's possible to use something like SNORQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to fetch data directly from website databases.
There is a very good Python package to fetch data from websites without using GUI: [requests](http://python-requests.org)

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```